# Segmentation error when using a pointer to an array

Tags: c

When the function get_poly is run, it gives me a segmentation error. Some of the placeholders and stuff were an attempt to bug fix. I really have no idea what is causing this.

```
//Weston Sapusek, cop3515
//This program outputs the polynomial of a number given coefficients for each exponent.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void get_poly(double *coeff, int N);
void eval_poly(double *coeff, double base, int N);

int main(void)
{
    int N; //max exponent
    double base;

    printf("Please enter the power of your polynomial: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    printf("Please enter the base number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &base);

    double a[N];
    double *coeff;
    coeff = &a[0];

    get_poly(coeff, N);
    coeff = 0; //reset the coefficient pointer

    eval_poly(coeff, base, N);  
    return 0;
}

void get_poly(double *coeff, int N) {
    printf("Enter %d coeffecients of the function, in order: ", N);
    int i = 0;
    double placeholder;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        scanf("%lf", &placeholder);
        *coeff = placeholder;
        coeff++;
    }
}

void eval_poly(double *coeff, double base, int N)
{
    int i = 0;
    double x = 0; //total

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        x+= *coeff * base;
    }
    printf("%lf", x);
}
```

Comment: Does it compile? double a[N]; here N should be constant

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @Asesh: Variable Length Array, a dubious feature of C99 which can be used as a extension in C++ by default with GCC.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the problematic code:

```
get_poly(coeff, N);
coeff = 0; //reset the coeffecient pointer

eval_poly(coeff, base, N);
```

You *reset the coeffecient pointer*, after that `coeff` is NULL. You then  call `eval_poly` and de-reference what would be a NULL pointer `coeff` inside `eval_poly` function. That caused the segfault.

Answer (score 0):

just remove this line:

```
  coeff = 0; //reset the coeffecient pointer
```

`coeff` is not changed by `get_poly` because it's sent by value (although it's a pointer)

Setting  `coeff = 0;` makes it point to an invalid memory address.